# How to pass parameter to global error controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using global error controller for handling bad request in my ASP.NET Core MVC app.

I have

```
app.UseStatusCodePagesWithReExecute("/error/{0}");
```

In my Startup.cs and an action in ErrorController like this

```
        [Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
        public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
        {
            var feature = HttpContext.Features.Get<IStatusCodeReExecuteFeature>();
            ViewData["ErrorPathBase"] = feature?.OriginalPath;
            ViewData["ErrorQuerystring"] = feature?.OriginalQueryString;

            _logger
                .ForContext("OriginalPath", feature?.OriginalPath)
                .ForContext("OriginalQueryString", feature?.OriginalQueryString)
                .Warning($"User has reached {statusCode} page.");

            switch (statusCode)
            {
                case 404: return PartialView("_BadRequest");
                case 400: return PartialView("_BadRequest");
                case 403: return PartialView("_AccessDenied");
                default: return PartialView("_BadRequest");
            }
        }
```

Each time I return

```
return NotFound();
```

inside my app, ErrorController is invoked. How can I pass some additional parameters to  return NotFound like this

```
return NotFound("returnUrl"});
```

and still hit that HttpStatusCodeHandler action?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContext.Items` for this purpose

```
HttpContext.Items["SomeItem"] = "Some value";
return NotFound();
```

**ErrorController**

```
[Route("Error/{statusCode}")]
public IActionResult HttpStatusCodeHandler(int statusCode)
{
    object someItem = HttpContext.Items["SomeItem"];
    //...
}
```